# How to stream video via bittorrent in an HTML5 <video>-tag?

Tags: html, html5-video, p2p, bittorrent

How to use p2p-next.org´s [SwarmPlayer v2](http://swarmplayer.p2p-next.org/#doc.html)..?

I´am trying to use this for an site, Do not have the money to pay for alot of bandwidth.

So I need steam the videos via bittorrent.

I´am using Ubuntu 12.10 for my testing.

Below is the HTML5-code.

```
    <video style="width:544px;height:304px;">   
    <source src="tribe://http://url2torrent.net/torrent/511640ccc3acb404f246f391.torrent">
    <source src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Moederdag_%281925%29.ogv" >
    </video>
```

The key part beside the `<video>`-tag is the `tribe://`:

> `<source src="tribe://http://url2torrent.net/torrent/511640ccc3acb404f246f391.torrent">`

When I load the HTML5-page and go to: `http://127.0.0.1:6877/webUI`

Then I can´t see the video download.. :(

[image]

I got it to download the video ones... after an hour time.. for only 45mb.. not god..

So is the SwarmPlayer-p2p-style just slow?

Can it be speed up?

Or is there an better player to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be something wrong with the HTTP fallback. If you try with an Ogg video directly seeded by BitTorrent (and a playtime field) it still works. E.g. try

http://ca.isohunt.com/download/280788549/5aa6a160a7470b00e4b3d0ee824333fb7c934ca7.torrent

as source. See c:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zzzzz.default\extensio
ns\tribe@p2pnext.org\bgprocess\SwarmEngine.exe.log (check swarmengined script for Linux location) for the log of the BitTorrent engine.

Comment: Cool dude.. thanks.. You made my day :)  so the code look like this now: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1677806/

Comment: You can play any Ogg video from a torrent. Firefox works better if it knows the duration. For this it depends on a X-Content-Duration header which the SwarmPlayer will set if there is a 'playtime' key in the top-level of the .torrent with a [hh:]mm:ss time specification for the duration. So take any Ogg .torrent, add a playtime to it and SwarmPlayer will play it fine.